# get AppBundle by id design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

So after successfully POSTing a new AppBundle, I cannot GET the details back anymore from `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/appbundles/:id`. It results in a bad request 400

I'm using the fully qualified id, it's returned from the post as `ClientId.name`. Since there is no alias yet, there is no `+label`. I can do a GET on `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/appbundles` and it will return my AppBundle with the `+$LATEST` label just fine. I tried appending that to the fully qualified id, or the version number, same result. I can GET existing (already shared) AppBundles just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of non-shared app bundles, fully qualified ID *must include* the alias. Which means that in order to make the GET request, you will first need to create or update an alias that will point to the version that you have just created.

Comment: Thanks Petr, good to have clarity on that! As an aside, the :id to set the alias must be an unqualified id.

Comment: No worries! Yeah, when setting an alias, you only use the unqualified ID. I assume that's because you can only set aliases for app bundles you own.